# Python Gtk3 Entry set placeholder text

Tags: python, gtk3

I tried to set a grey italic placeholder text for Gtk.Entry but the entry is empty. Using Linux Mint 17.3 / Gtk Version 3.10.8

Whats wrong with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window()
box = Gtk.Box()
window.add(box)

entry = Gtk.Entry()
box.add(entry)

entry.set_placeholder_text("Filter")

window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Note that since the placeholder text gets removed when the entry received focus, using this feature is a bit problematic if the entry is given the initial focus in a window. Sometimes this can be worked around by delaying the initial focus setting until the first key event arrives.

Try to add a button and give it focus, it should work.

Comment: Thank you. If have to read the docs better :-)

http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Entry.html#Gtk.Entry.set_placeholder_text